# Xamarin.Auth with facebook results in state - Explicit flow

Tags: facebook, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing facebook login using the Xamarin.Auth component. I request a login by my backend (aspnet webapi) which returns a challenge result and my app gets a redirect to facebook login. At the same time of the redirect I also get a popup in the app saying "Invalid state from server. Possible forgery!" found it here in the source https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Auth/OAuth2Authenticator.cs

If I investigate the request I can see a state is generated in the OAuth2Authenticator class.

My question, is the best way to handle authentication in the current setup or should I avoid to let my own backend redirect the app login. Instead let the app login directly with facebook and the send the token from facebook to my backend, where I'll verify it with a call to https://graph.facebook.com/me and then generate my own auth_token if the call is valid?

I just read Instagram login docs https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

And it's exactly what I meant, Implicit or Explicit flow. For me Explicit is not working with Xamarin.Auth against facebook, due to the state.

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

Little late to the game here on this one, but I've run in to the same issue recently with an ASP.NET web API that I'm trying to connect to.

What I ended up doing was extending the `OAuth2Authenticator` class and overriding `OnPageEncountered()`.  See below for a Xamarin.Android implementation:

```
public class DroidOAuth2Authenticator : OAuth2Authenticator
{
    ...

    protected override void OnPageEncountered(Uri url, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> query, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> fragment)
    {
        // Remove state from dictionaries. 
        // We are ignoring request state forgery status 
        // as we're hitting an ASP.NET service which forwards 
        // to a third-party OAuth service itself
        if (query.ContainsKey("state"))
        {
            query.Remove("state");
        }

        if (fragment.ContainsKey("state"))
        {
            fragment.Remove("state");
        }

        base.OnPageEncountered(url, query, fragment);
    }
}
```

Granted this removes the security warning for the user, but not sure of any other way around it.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but I get "OAuth2Authenticator' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments". How do I properly extend a class in Xamarin? I'm on Xamarin.Auth 1.5.

Comment: @user2666194 You should be able to extend OAuth2Authenticator with the code above, just remove the "...".  It sounds like you're attempting to call the original class without passing any params to the constructor.  It should work if you call it using: ```new DroidOAuth2Authenticator(clientId: "self", scope: "", authorizeUrl: new Uri("..."), redirectUrl: new Uri("..."));```